# node child_process exec : run as administrator

Tags: node.js, command-prompt, child-process

in node, thanks to child_process , I manage to launch visual studio .

```
 var vsExe = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"';
        let commande = `${vsExe}`;
        var exec = require("child_process").exec;
        exec(commande, function callback(error, stdout, stderr) {
           //callback
        });
```

I would like to do the same thing but as if I had run it as administrator (as if I did a right click and choose 'run as administrator')

[image] 
 [image]

Do you know ho to do it please?

Comment: According to microsoft/terminal github, you can't elavate permissions to an open terminal:
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/632

So, I suppose you can try running the code from an administrator termianl.
(open CMD as administrator > $ `node startCodeDevenv.js`).

Comment: Thank you. indeed I am  using this workaround

Comment: @YanivPeretz can you elaborate about this workaround?